# Is it better to use arrays or a queue when merging two sorted arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, queue, mergesort

I'm working on a programming practice site that asked to implement a method that merges two sorted arrays. This is my solution:

```
  public static int[] merge(int[] arrLeft, int[] arrRight){
    int[] merged = new int[arrRight.length + arrLeft.length];

    Queue<Integer> leftQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Integer> rightQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < arrLeft.length ; i ++){
        leftQueue.add(arrLeft[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arrRight.length; i ++){
        rightQueue.add(arrRight[i]);
    }

    int index = 0;
    while (!leftQueue.isEmpty() || !rightQueue.isEmpty()){

        int largerLeft = leftQueue.isEmpty() ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : leftQueue.peek();
        int largerRight = rightQueue.isEmpty() ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : rightQueue.peek();

        if(largerLeft > largerRight){
            merged[index] = largerRight;
            rightQueue.poll();
        } else{
            merged[index] = largerLeft;
            leftQueue.poll();
        }

        index ++;
    }
    return merged;
   }
```

But this is the official solution:

```
public static int[] merge(int[] arrLeft, int[] arrRight){
    // Grab the lengths of the left and right arrays
    int lenLeft = arrLeft.length;
    int lenRight = arrRight.length;
    // Create a new output array with the size = sum of the lengths of left and right
    // arrays
    int[] arrMerged = new int[lenLeft+lenRight];
    // Maintain 3 indices, one for the left array, one for the right and one for 
    // the merged array
    int indLeft = 0, indRight = 0, indMerged = 0;
    // While neither array is empty, run a while loop to merge
    // the smaller of the two elements, starting at the leftmost position of 
    // both arrays
    while(indLeft < lenLeft && indRight < lenRight){
        if(arrLeft[indLeft] < arrRight[indRight])
            arrMerged[indMerged++] = arrLeft[indLeft++];
        else
            arrMerged[indMerged++] = arrRight[indRight++];
    }
    // Another while loop for when the left array still has elements left
    while(indLeft < lenLeft){
        arrMerged[indMerged++] = arrLeft[indLeft++];
    }
    // Another while loop for when the right array still has elements left
    while(indRight < lenRight){
        arrMerged[indMerged++] = arrRight[indRight++];
    }
    return arrMerged;
}
```

Apparently, all the other solutions by users on the site did not make use of a queue as well. I'm wondering if using a Queue is less efficient? Could I be penalized for using a queue in an interview for example?

Comment: Are you sure you are not losing any value from any array? I suspect your code would lose some indices.

Answer (score 1):

As the question already states that the left and right input *arrays* are *sorted*, this gives you a hint that you should be able to solve the problem without requiring a data structure other than an array for the output.

In a real interview, it is likely that the interviewer will ask you to talk through your thought process while you are coding the solution. They may state that they want the solution implemented with certain constraints. It is very important to make sure that the problem is well defined before you start your coding. Ask as many questions as you can think of to constrain the problem as much as possible before starting.

When you are done implementing your solution, you could mention the time and space complexity of your implementation and suggest an alternative, more efficient solution.

For example, when describing your implementation you could talk about the following:

- There is overhead when creating the queues
- The big O notation / time and space complexity of your solution
- You are unnecessarily iterating over every element of the left and right input array to create the queues before you do any merging
- etc...

These types of interview questions are common when applying for positions at companies like Google, Microsoft, Amazon, and some tech startups. To prepare for such questions, I recommend you work through problems in books such as [Cracking the Coding Interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984782850). The book covers how to approach such problems, and the interview process for these kinds of companies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but your solution with queues is horrible.

You are copying all elements to auxiliary dynamic data structures (which can be highly costly because of memory allocations), then back to the destination array.

A big "disadvantage" of merging is that it requires twice the storage space as it cannot be done in-place (or at least no the straightforward way). But you are spoiling things to a much larger extent by adding extra copies and overhead, unnecessarily.

The true solution is to copy directly from source to destination, leading to simpler and much more efficient code.

Also note that using a sentinel value (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) when one of the queues is exhausted is a false good idea because it adds extra comparisons when you know the outcome in advance. It is much better to split in three loops as in the reference code.

Lastly, your solution can fail when the data happens to contain `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.